# How to assign vector of strings as variable names, in for loop, in data.table, in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have been searching for this a long time and never found suitable answer here. I have a variable "extern" which is a vector containing names of my data frames:

```
extern <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
extern <– c("altitude.csv", "area.csv", "farmland.csv", "GDPpercapita.csv", "population.csv")
```

I can load them into R like this and the characters are converted to variables. It works for me assuming my wd is the folder same as data.

```
for (i in 1:length(extern)) assign(extern[i], fread(extern[i], sep = ","))
```

But this is only case that works for me. Now I want to iterate through loaded datasets and replace all commas nad % signs by nothing "". If I put a single dataset (instead of extern[i]) there, the code works but when put to for cycle it throws an error.

```
for (i in 1:length(extern)) {
  mutate_all(extern[i], function(x) {
    str_replace_all(string = x, pattern = ",", replacement = "")
    str_replace_all(x, pattern = "%", replacement = "")})
}
```

> Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") :    no applicable method for
> 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "character"

So I tried similar think with assign() as before without any success, than somebody used eval(parse()) combo and many different thinks.

```
for (i in 1:length(extern)) {
  assign(extern[i], mutate_all(extern[i], function(x) {
    str_replace_all(string = x, pattern = ",", replacement = "")
    str_replace_all(x, pattern = "%", replacement = "")}))
```

This is quite general problem, I encountered it many times and nothing worked so every time I had to go around. But now I have so many files that it is not possible to do it manually. Same problem is for example in data.table - I have stored column names in a vector and I wanted to do whatever. If you write there the name of the vector the data.table takes it as a name of single column and do not evaluate it. Also it is usually needed to cbind() or rbind() these files like this:

```
data <- rbindlist(l = list("altitude.csv", "area.csv", "farmland.csv", "GDPpercapita.csv", "population.csv"), idcol = "id")
```

and id like to have it easier way something like below - extern is a vector full of names (character strings)

```
rbindlist(l = extern, idcol = "id")
```

in this case it is possible to store names in the list because function itself accepts list of names, but majority of other functions including mutate_all() I used as an example, accepts variable not a character string as a name.

I hope somebody has same issue or some other way how to do it, because I really don't know and I spend searching like half year.

Comment: You can use `get()` on a character string to get the object it refers to--not sure how well that works with `dplyr`'s non-standard evaluation. The more common way to do this is to [make a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207) and iterate over the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common situation which can be handled with ease by using a *list*.

This is what I would do if the data files are different in structure, i.e., columns differ in names, data types, or order:

```
library(data.table)
file_names <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
list_of_df <- lapply(file_names, fread)
list_of_df <- setNames(list_of_df, file_names)
list_of_df
```

> ```
> $area.csv
>    id         name
> 1:  1  normal name
> 2:  2   with,comma
> 3:  3 with%percent
>
> $farmland.csv
>    id         name
> 1:  1  normal name
> 2:  2   with,comma
> 3:  3 with%percent
>
> $GDPpercapita.csv
>    id         name
> 1:  1  normal name
> 2:  2   with,comma
> 3:  3 with%percent
> ```

Note that I have made up three sample files for demonstration. See *Data* section for details.

The elements of the resulting *list* object `list_of_df` are named like the files the data were loaded from.

Now, we can operate on the elements of the list using `lapply()` or a `for` loop, e.g.,

```
lapply(
  list_of_df, 
  function(df) df[, lapply(.SD, function(col) if (is.character(col)) stringr::str_remove_all(col, "[,%]") else col)]
  )

$area.csv
   id        name
1:  1 normal name
2:  2   withcomma
3:  3 withpercent

$farmland.csv
   id        name
1:  1 normal name
2:  2   withcomma
3:  3 withpercent

$GDPpercapita.csv
   id        name
1:  1 normal name
2:  2   withcomma
3:  3 withpercent
```

Note that the code to remove `,` and `%` has been simplified.

`lapply()` has the advantage over a `for` loop that is returns a *list* again which is convenient for subsequent processing steps.

---

As a side note: there is a speciality with `data.table` as it is able to *update by reference*, i.e., without copying the data.table. So, we can update `list_of_df` *in place* which might be a benefit in terms of speed and memory consumption for large datasets:

```
address(list_of_df) # just for demonstration
for (df in list_of_df) {
  cols <- which(sapply(df, is.character))
  df[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, stringr::str_remove_all, "[,%]"), .SDcols = cols]
}
address(list_of_df)
```

The calls to `address(list_of_df)` before and after the `for` loop have been added to demonstrate that  `list_of_df` still occupies the same storage location but has been changed in place.

```
list_of_df
```

> ```
> $area.csv
>    id        name
> 1:  1 normal name
> 2:  2   withcomma
> 3:  3 withpercent
>
> $farmland.csv
>    id        name
> 1:  1 normal name
> 2:  2   withcomma
> 3:  3 withpercent
>
> $GDPpercapita.csv
>    id        name
> 1:  1 normal name
> 2:  2   withcomma
> 3:  3 withpercent
> ```

---

In case the datasets read from file have a similar structure, i.e. same name, order and data type of columns, we can combine the single pieces into one large dataset using `rbindlist()`

My preferred workflow for this use case is along

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
file_names <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
big_df <- lapply(file_names, fread) %>% 
  set_names(file_names) %>% 
  rbindlist(idcol = "file_name")
big_df
```

> ```
>           file_name id         name
> 1:         area.csv  1  normal name
> 2:         area.csv  2   with,comma
> 3:         area.csv  3 with%percent
> 4:     farmland.csv  1  normal name
> 5:     farmland.csv  2   with,comma
> 6:     farmland.csv  3 with%percent
> 7: GDPpercapita.csv  1  normal name
> 8: GDPpercapita.csv  2   with,comma
> 9: GDPpercapita.csv  3 with%percent
> ```

Note that `rbindlist()` has created an id column from the names of the list elements. This allows for distinguishing the origin of each row.

Working with one uniform data structure simplifies subsequent processing

```
cols <- which(sapply(big_df, is.character))
big_df[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, stringr::str_remove_all, "[,%]"), .SDcols = cols]
big_df
```

> ```
>           file_name id        name
> 1:         area.csv  1 normal name
> 2:         area.csv  2   withcomma
> 3:         area.csv  3 withpercent
> 4:     farmland.csv  1 normal name
> 5:     farmland.csv  2   withcomma
> 6:     farmland.csv  3 withpercent
> 7: GDPpercapita.csv  1 normal name
> 8: GDPpercapita.csv  2   withcomma
> 9: GDPpercapita.csv  3 withpercent
> ```

---

As the OP is using `mutate()` here is an all "*tidyverse*" approach. It does essentially the same as the data.table versions above:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
file_names <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
list_of_df <- map(file_names, readr::read_csv) %>% 
  set_names(file_names)

list_of_df %>% 
  map( ~ mutate(.x, across(where(is.character), ~ stringr::str_remove_all(.x, "[,%]"))))
```

> ```
> $area.csv
> # A tibble: 3 x 2
>      id name       
>   <dbl> <chr>      
> 1     1 normal name
> 2     2 withcomma  
> 3     3 withpercent
>
> $farmland.csv
> # A tibble: 3 x 2
>      id name       
>   <dbl> <chr>      
> 1     1 normal name
> 2     2 withcomma  
> 3     3 withpercent
>
> $GDPpercapita.csv
> # A tibble: 3 x 2
>      id name       
>   <dbl> <chr>      
> 1     1 normal name
> 2     2 withcomma  
> 3     3 withpercent
> ```

`map()` is the equivalent of base R's `lapply()`. Also `readr::read_csv()` is used instead of `data.table`'s `fread()`.

### Data

**Caveat:** The code below will create 3 files in the current working directory!

```
library(data.table)
dummy <- data.table(id = 1:3, name = c("normal name", "with,comma", "with%percent"))
extern <- c("area.csv", "farmland.csv", "GDPpercapita.csv")
for (fn in extern) fwrite(dummy, fn)
```

The code saves a dummy data.table three times as csv file to disk using three different file names.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for. Perfect explanation and I think many people looking for this. You made it so easy @Uwe. Now I have many more questions :D

Answer (score 1):

Building on Gregor's comment, here's a way to use `get()` plus `:=` from `data.table`:

```
for(x in extern){
    get(x)[ , colnames(get(x)) := lapply(.SD, str_replace_all, pattern = ",|%", replacement = "")]
}
```

I believe that using the `|` in `str_replace_all()` should allow you to only call that function once and still achieve the desired result. If some of your columns are not character and don't need to be replaced, something like this may be better:

```
for(x in extern){
    charCols <- colnames(get(x))[ get(x)[ , sapply(.SD, is.character)] ]
    get(x)[ , c(charCols) := lapply(.SD, str_replace_all, pattern = ",|%", replacement = ""), .SDcols = charCols]
}
```

Outside of these solutions, I also second Gregor's suggestion of storing the dataframes in a list and then iterating over that.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is you cannot assign the return value of fread to a vector, it must be a list. So the syntax assign(extern[i], fread) will not work. Second, in your str_replace_all, the result of the first str_replace_all command is lost. This code works:

```
extern = c("altitude.csv", "area.csv")
dat=list()
for (i in 1:length(extern)) {
  dat[[i]]=read.csv(extern[i], header=FALSE)
}
dat

[[1]]
     V1    V2
1  56%,  34,3
2 %%%,4 3,%6%

[[2]]
                V1
1            ik%if
2            fel3,
3               ,%

for (i in 1:length(extern)) {
  dat[[i]]=mutate(dat[[i]], across(everything(), function(x) {
    return(str_replace_all(string = x, pattern = "[,%]", replacement = ""))
  }))
}
dat

[[1]]
  V1  V2
1 56 343
2  4  36

[[2]]
               V1
1            ikif
2            fel3
```

Comment: Actually assign(extern[i], fread) did work, I don't know why but I found it also here just in another tread. But still can you explain what is the difference storing char string in vector or in the list? Because the name of the dataset is still character string, how it is possible that R recognize char string stored in the list as variable name but not from a vector? So the whole point is just use list not a vector and thats it. Omg I feel like total idiot :D

Comment: @GrayJackal fread returns a data frame, so you need to define a list to hold its return value. It only looked like that line worked, but it actually had problems that showed up later on.